# EF Core: how do I omit properties with "invalid" column name only on update/insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a very specific problem for EF Core. I create my entity using `.ToSqlQuery`.

In this query, I join a table with various other tables to combine them into one single model, which is sadly necessary. Now, this works perfectly if I want to read the data.

But if I want to add a model using this entity to the database using `DBSet.Add`, it fails telling me "invalid column name".

Yeah - of course it's invalid because my property is in a joined entity. And this context does not exist when updating the entity, and it can't resolve the relationship.

I need some kind of solution for separating a view object from a write object. I even tried inheritance once, but then I would need some strange discriminator, I just want the same model once as editable and one as not-editable

To make it easier to understand I will add an example: I have a `Job` table with base properties

```
Id | JobTypeId | JobStatusId | ...
```

Then I unfortunately have a lot of plugin-classes like `JobStatus`:

```
Id | Name
```

`JobType`:

```
Id | Name
```

So following EF Core, I now need an entity for the `JobStatus` and `JobType` only to get to this name!

But I would rather like to have `JobModel` like this:

```
Id | JobTypeName | JobStatusName | ...
```

Comment: I don't recall trying it the way you describe it, but if your read only properties were in a subclass, and you casted the subclass to the base class and add it to the context's baseclass collection, it will ignore the RO props, no? I'm still trying to figure out how you came to download this enhanced entity, and then want to add it again as the non enhanced version - is it not simpler to just have a normal related set of entities that you populate? Or AutoMapper the DB ents back and forth to a DTO - the DTO representing the combined, and the DB ents representing the separated ones

Comment: How about to add [NotMapped] attribute?

Comment: You shouldn't mix the temporary entity you use to use that special query. Instead, map the data into the actual entity object you have configured.

Comment: The problem is the database i'm using has a lot of useless tables, where i only need one single property. replicating all of them would be a huge overhead in code, i would hate that.

what i want is take only this one property, without any new model. and this is why i'm doing the Join in the ToSqlQuery on the modelBuilder.

But if i use ToSqlQuery it throws when adding the model...

Comment: I agree with @CaiusJard, i think having a mapper that maps the entities representing the (legacy) database tables and your domain objects you use for your business logic back and forth would be a good and simple solution.

Comment: i don't know Automapper and never used it... it looks like it can Map one Object to another. so doesn't this mean i need to now create even more objects? first: all objects which are reflecting a database table + the DTOs to map into?

if so this is probably the opposite of a solution... 

I just want to puzzle myself an entity together without maintaining more C# code. like
"take prop A from table A, propB from tableB, ..." and build object A

Comment: There is typically a disjoint between e.g. the "create a new employee" web page and the 7 tables in the db that get some data update or insert when a new employee is created. For this reason we have an object that represents the data the "create new emp" page needs and then 7 other objects that represent the data in the tables, and we map from the 1 to the 7 and back. We don't try to make some massive fudge of the 7 in a graph support the needs of the create employee page for various reasons, one such being we don't follow a rule of "avoid creating new classes wherever possible"

Comment: Re use is good, but taking classes meant to support db side ents and abusing them into supporting front end makes things harder later on down the line; changes in one class ripple through the codebase, and they only stop when they come up against some decoupling such as this notion of having dedicated objects for different uses. Taken to the extreme, we wouldnt create new classes at all; everything would just be an `object[]` so I'd advocate not starting out from the perspective of "more classes is bad"

Comment: I do get your point, but the data i'm talking about is not frontend data.
i don't want to avoid adding additional classes. i want to avoid adding additional *useless* classes! 
our database is so hardcore splitted that it will heavily reduce code quality if i do a 1:1 mapping. imagine having an object and 50% of it's properties being a new table where there's a 1:1 mapping.
our database scheme is really stupid so i don't want to replicate it, but i also can't change it. maaping is the only option left